# Enviar post a la misma pagina sin recargar

Tags: php

Se puede enviar post a la misma pagina php para luego yo poner if `isset $_POST ['data']` haga algo? Porque lo que quiero es que al dar click se sume un elemento en mi array php que guardo en la sesion pero no quiero ver el efecto de recargado de la pagina

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un poco de código PHP que recibe los datos y HTML del formulario que los envía?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo mínimo de los datos que quieres enviar (el HTML de tu formulario) y un mínimo de código PHP para saber lo que has intentado hasta ahora (lo que has conseguido aunque se recargue la página) no podremos ayudarte. Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Por cierto, ¿usas jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de empezar he de decirte que es mala idea almacenar gran cantidad de datos en las variables de sesión. Tienden a ralentizar la ejecución de cada uno de los scripts que usen `session_start()` y, además, aumenta el uso de memoria.

Una vez aclarado ese punto, lo que necesitas es enviar los datos al servidor mediante [`XMLHttpRequest` (más conocido como `XHR` o `AJAX`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Dicho envío no provoca el refresco de la página y permite modificar mediante javascript su contenido de acuerdo con la respuesta obtenida.

La biblioteca de funciones jQuery te facilitará mucho el trabajo a través de [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://tu_pagina_web.es/tu_script.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: datos,
}).done(function( datos ) {
  console.log(datos);
);
```

En el ejemplo que te pongo más abajo he usado la propiedad `data` para que los datos estén disponibles en `$_POST['data']` tal y como solicitas en la pregunta:

```
<?php
/* Iniciamos el uso de las variables de sesión */
session_start();
/* Comprobamos si el campo "data" ha sido recibido por POST */
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    /* Agregamos los datos recibidos a la variable de sesión */
    array_push($_SESSION['datos'], $_POST['data']);
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    die(json_encode(true));
}
```

Como puedes observar he enviado una cabecera HTTP llamada `Content-type` con el valor `application/json; charset=utf-8` para que el valor devuelto por el PHP sea interpretado como un dato nativo de javascript.

En la prueba de concepto, además, he creado una segunda petición `GET` para refrescar el contenido de la variable de sesión en la página web sin necesitar refrescar su contenido.

Aquí tienes el código completo de la prueba de concepto:

```
<?php
/* Iniciamos el uso de las variables de sesión */
session_start();
/* Si aún no existe la clave de sesión requerida la creamos con una matriz vacía */
if (!isset($_SESSION['datos'])) {
    $_SESSION['datos'] = [];
}
/* Comprobamos si el campo "data" ha sido recibido por POST */
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    /* Agregamos los datos recibidos a la variable de sesión */
    array_push($_SESSION['datos'], $_POST['data']);
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    die(json_encode(true));
}
/* Comprobamos si el campo "actualizar" ha sido recibido por GET */
if (isset($_GET['actualizar'])) {
    /* Entregamos los datos codificados en JSON */
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    die(json_encode($_SESSION['datos'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Título de ejemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Formulario:</h3>
    <p><input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Introduzca un texto aquí" size="50" />
    <button id="boton">Actualizar datos</button></p>
    <h3>Resultado del envío:</h3>
    <pre id="resultado">-</pre>
    <h3>Contenido de <code>$_SESSION['datos']</code>:</h3>
    <pre id="datos"><?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_SESSION['datos'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)) ?></pre>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        /* Cuando pulsemos en el botón enviaremos la petición POST */
        $( '#boton' ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: <?= json_encode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>,
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    data: $( '#texto' ).val(),
                },
            }).done(function( datos ) {
                /* Mostramos el resultado de agregar los datos */
                $( '#resultado' ).text(datos);
                /* Limpiamos el campo de texto del formulario y colocamos el foco allí de nuevo */
                $( '#texto' ).val('').focus();
                /* Solicitamos al servidor que nos envíe los datos almacenados en la variable de sesión */
                $.ajax({
                    url: <?= json_encode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>,
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {
                        actualizar: true,
                    },
                }).done(function( datos, resultado, xhr ) {
                    /* Mostramos el contenido de la variable de sesión tal y como nos la envía el PHP */
                    $( '#datos' ).text(xhr.responseText);
                    /* Por consola muestro los datos nativos de javascript */
                    console.log(datos);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que estas buscando es enviar una variable de un formulario para sumarla a un array , lo mejor que puedes hacer es almacenar con javascript esa variable y crear un array , ya despues si quieres mandarla con php la mandas con metodo post o la subes directamente a tu base de datos.
Si esto no te vale puedes intentar pasar la variable con GET.
Espero que te sirva!

```js
var Tuarray = [];   //Creamos un array

//Cojemos la variable 
var variable = document.getElementById('tu_varible').value ; 

//Indentamos al final del array la variable separado por comas
Tuarray.push( variable + ",");
```